# Unexpected JSON output for mysql table data in PHP

Tags: php, json

My following code works fine.

```
$arr = array();
$str = "Acme® Foundation";
$arr[] = array( "title" => $str);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

--------- Output is as expected

```
[{"title":"Acme\u00ae Foundation"}]
```

but if I retrieve same string from database table then it returns null

```
$arr = array();
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$str = $row["title"];
$arr[] = array( "title" => $str);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

**--------- Output is not as expected**

```
[{"title":null}]
```

Can someone please guide as I am very new too php and mysql.
**If I don't use ® symbol then it works just fine.**

TIA,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The manual states that json_encode only works with UTF-8 encoded data](https://www.php.net/json_encode). Could it be that the value retrieved from the database has another encoding?

Try `echo json_encode(utf8_encode($arr));` and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Yes utf8_encode works,
`$arr[] = array( "title" => utf8_encode($str));`

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $r[] = array(
      "id" => $row['id'],
      "data1" => $row['data1']
    );
   )
$encoded = json_encode($r);
```